# Copy data to another sheet Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets vice excel to automate some web pulls and am having trouble setting up the script language

I have the following in the script editor, but I am getting an error (below). How do I amend this code? New to this script, only every used VBA and even then, I'm self taught :)

"Incorrect range width, was 8 but should be 6 (line 8, file "Code")"

```
function StorePullValue() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Spring_Pull');  
var values = sheet.getRange("A5:G5").getValues()[0];  
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Spring_Tracker'); // where to store the data
var height = sheet2.getLastRow();   
sheet2.insertRowAfter(height);
sheet2.getRange(height+1, 1, 1, 6).setValues([[new Date()].concat(values)]); 
}
```

Comment: change 6 to 8 ?

Comment: Ugh, always the simple stuff. I got hung up on the "should be 6" part of the error...and since it was already 6...thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A5:G5").getValues()[0];
```

Given the range "A5:G5", this assigns the first row of the range to `values`. Rows A-G ends up being 7 elements in the array.

```
[[new Date()].concat(values)]
```

This results in a new array composed of a date string and the 7 values from above, resulting in an 8 value array. This is the source of the `was 8` portion of the error message.